# WGET, Cookies and 302 Redirect

Tags: command-line, cookies, centos, wget

I want to use WGET to download some pics from a memberarea of some site. This site is password protected. I have logged in successfullly and save the cookies. However, I still cant download the pics, becasue of the 302 Redirect. Could any one do me favor and take a look at this? Thanks a lot.

```
wget --load-cookies=examplecookies  http://members.example.com/membersarea/0004.jpg
--2010-12-18 18:58:50--  http://members.example.com/membersarea/0004.jpg
Resolving members.example.com... 12.34.56.78
Connecting to members.example.com|12.34.56.78|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fmembersarea%2f0004.jpg [following]
--2010-12-18 18:58:50--  http://members.example.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fmembersarea%2f0004.jpg
Reusing existing connection to members.example.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /membersarea/default.aspx [following]
--2010-12-18 18:58:50--  http://members.example.com/membersarea/default.aspx
Reusing existing connection to members.example.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 61898 (60K) [text/html]
Saving to: `default.aspx'

100%[===================================================================================>] 61,898      --.-K/s   in 0.1s

2010-12-18 18:58:51 (572 KB/s) - `default.aspx' saved [61898/61898]
```

The `default.aspx` is the front page of the membersarea, which means I have logged in successfully.

I have done some google search, and I add the `--user-agent="Mozilla/4.0"`, but it still wont work:

```
wget --user-agent="Mozilla/4.0" --load-cookies=examplecookies  http://members.example.com/membersarea/0004.jpg
```

The result is the same.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to always have trouble with wget and cookies (trying to make wget use my Mozilla cookies, etc...) so I switched to using the Perl library [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize).  It handles cookies for you as well as all of the usual things you'd expect out of a browser, like 302 handling and history.

An simple example that logs into a site, grabs all JPGs and clicks a "Next" link for pagination:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use File::Slurp;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$mech->get('http://example.com/login') || die;
$mech->submit_form( form_name => 'login_form',
                    fields => { username => 'me',
                                password => 'secret' } ) || die;

while (1) {
   for my $link ($mech->links) {
      my $url = $link->url;
      if ($url =~ /(image_\d+\.jpg)\z/) {
         my $file = $1;
         $mech->get($url);
         File::Slurp::write_file($file, $mech->content);
         $mech->back; # like the browser back button                                
      }
   }
   # look at next page, if any                                                      
   my $result = $mech->follow_link(text_regex => qr/Next/);
   if (!$result) {
      last;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi I have already solved my problem with the help of Flashgot (A firefox addons.) Here is how: Right click the pic's url and select "Flash got the link", then you can download the pic successfully. Then take a look at the logs of Flashgot, and copy the cookies infromation to a txt file. That is the cookies that wget need. Then use wget with that cookies and I download the files successfully. Thanks a lot for your help. I may use Perl later. :)